# What if we keep calling semGive multiple times without semTake in binary semaphore? What will be the behavior?

Tags: c++, multithreading, operating-system, semaphore, binary-semaphore

We have created a binary semaphore with `semBcreate`.

Code fragments:

```
semTake(with 10s wait); // it will be called only once during restart
semGive();              //this will be called from multiple thread.
```

so here we will have lots of `semGive()` called without any `semTake()`. As it was called only once during reboot of device to achieve synchronization.

Please help me answering this, we don't see any problem but what if device will run for long time and there will be lots of `semGive` called in binary semaphore?

We tried calling `semGive` many times, couldn't notice any potential issue. But we need to understand if there is any cons of doing this way.

Comment: What does the documentation of semGive, semTake and semBcreate (whatever that is) say?

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.ecb.torontomu.ca/~courses/ee8205/Data-Sheets/Tornado-VxWorks/vxworks/ref/semBLib.html) (assuming this is the right one) is silent on what happens when you give a full binary semaphore. But there is no obvious mechanism by which it could break later. So if it appears to work for you, it works and is unlikely to explode.

Comment: Even if it works, it seems like an indication for a flawed design. Why do you have to release the semaphore multiple times ? Usually it should be coupled with a call to take the semaphore.

Answer (score 0):

> We tried calling semGive many times, couldn't notice any potential issue

That is almost always a Bad Idea. You should go with what the documentation says. If the documentation does not *guarantee* that the semaphore (or any other thing) always will behave in the way that your program needs it to behave, then you are setting yourself up for future trouble.

What happens if some library developer decides that the current implementation is buggy,* and they fix the bug? The bug fix goes out as part of an OS update, your customers accept the update, and suddenly your application stops working for everybody, everywhere, all at once.

Been there. Done that. It wasn't fun.

I've never heard of this `semBCreate`. But @teapot418 found [a page](https://www.ecb.torontomu.ca/%7Ecourses/ee8205/Data-Sheets/Tornado-VxWorks/vxworks/ref/semBLib.html) that might be for the same `semBCreate` that you are using. It *seems* to me as if *maybe* you can infer that multiple calls to `semGive(s)` with no `semTake(s,...)` in between will have the same effect as a single call to `semGive(s)`. If that's the behavior that your program requires, then you probably are OK.

On the other hand, the doc does not *explicitly* talk about that case,** so maybe you should shoot an email to the library authors just to be sure.

---

* The [documentation for the C++ standard libary's binary semaphore](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/counting_semaphore) pretty much guarantees that it will *not* behave the way your program expects a binary semaphore to behave.

** What you're doing is not the normal use-case for a binary semaphore.

Comment: I also found [this discussion](https://comp.os.vxworks.narkive.com/tOIls0gc/binary-semaphores-multiple-semgives-before-a-semtake) with a similar question. But as far as authoritative evidence goes, it's not much.